# How to change screen contrast of any android device?

Tags: android

How can I change the contrast of screen in android through programming in android. I searched so many blog, it was not mentioned any where. Is it possible to control the contrast if possible please provide me the sample code.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

see [this](http://android.programmerguru.com/how-to-change-screen-brightness-programmatically/) link may be help to you....

Also see code

```
 Settings.System.putInt(this.getContentResolver(),
        Settings.System.SCREEN_BRIGHTNESS, 20);

WindowManager.LayoutParams lp = getWindow().getAttributes();
lp.screenBrightness =0.2f;// 100 / 100.0f;
getWindow().setAttributes(lp);

startActivity(new Intent(this,RefreshScreen.class));
```

Comment: I want to control the "Contrast" not "Brightness". Can you suggest me how to do it?

Comment: I try to search the solution for screen contrast but not yet got proper solution... see  following for image contrast  http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/Change-Contrast-and-Brightness-of-IMAGE-programatically/td-p/323576

Answer (score -1):

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

```
boolean isFrontOn;
ImageButton btnFront;
SeekBar brightnessBar;
float brightness;
ContentResolver cResolver;
RelativeLayout overlayLayout;
String permissions[] = {"android.permission.WRITE_SETTING"};

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    btnFront = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btnFront);
    brightnessBar = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.brightnessBar);

    cResolver = getContentResolver();
    brightnessBar.setMax(255);
    brightnessBar.setKeyProgressIncrement(1);

    btnFront.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (!isFrontOn)
                turnFrontOn();
            else
                turnFrontOff();
        }
    });

    try {
        brightness = Settings.System.getInt(cResolver, Settings.System.SCREEN_BRIGHTNESS);
    } catch (Settings.SettingNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    int screenBrightness = (int) brightness;
    brightnessBar.setProgress(screenBrightness);

    brightnessBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
        int progressVal = 0;

        @Override
        public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {

            if (progress <= 20)
                progressVal = 20;
            else
                progressVal = progress;
        }

        @Override
        public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 23 || checkSelfPermission(permissions[0]) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_DENIED)
                Settings.System.putInt(cResolver, Settings.System.SCREEN_BRIGHTNESS, progressVal);
            else requestPermissions(permissions, 0);

        }
    });
}

@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
    super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
    if ( checkSelfPermission(permissions[0]) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        //ToDo your code here after checking permission
        /*
        i.e)  Settings.System.putInt(cResolver, Settings.System.SCREEN_BRIGHTNESS, progressVal);
         */
    }
}
```

}

try this in your code if your device API is greater than 22